# Can an Android application or activity call APIs in higher API levels?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible for an Android application with a given minimum API level (say 8 "Froyo") to conditionally use APIs that are only in higher API levels (e.g. the NFC APIs in level 10) for example by detecting for the presence of the API or API level at run-time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using reflection. Here's an article that shows how to do this on Android:

- <strike>[Backwards Compatibility for Applications](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html)</strike> [Backward compatibility for Android applications](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There's a pretty useful example on [Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html).